# How can i send % sign in the mail body which is not supporting HTML characters?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sendmail

I am really stuck on this.

what i am trying to do is sending plain text mail. but into that now i need so send the %(sign) in the mail but it is always sending junk character. I have already tried by converting it to "%25"(the hex code) but still no luck.

its very urgent. please help...

Comment: What happens if you just put `%`?

Comment: If it is a plain text email, you send a `%` as, well, `%`...

Comment: Then your code is broken somewhere else. SMTP uses 7-bit ascii, % is ascii code 0x25. You've got character code conversion issues in your code. Which you've not shown.

Comment: I am sending mail from mobile in iPhone and android App using phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

You escape the % character as

```
&#37;
```

Comment: Yes. "&" is also not supported in the mail. still thanks for your reply #Simon MacDonald

Answer (score 0):

If you really insit on wrapping a function round it

```
String.fromCharCode(37)
```

Use Simons its much neater tho.